# Where are the default content assist functions located in an xtext project

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I want to provide a cascading content assist for my xtext grammar.

Tried the conventional stuff. But that only provides content-assist only once. I already asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054097/how-to-add-cascading-content-assist-in-xtext-document) but got no help.

I realized that eclipse already has some cascading content-assist as a default. Trying to find those functions so that that I can refer to them for understanding how they provide such feature.

Expecting to find the default content-assist files in the project.

Comment: do you target eclipse, web, lsp?

Comment: I'm using eclipse.

Comment: with the proper grammar this will work ootb

Comment: I have shared the grammar on the Eclipse foundation forum. Kindly have a look at it and suggest any changes that might be required. Anyway it'll be wonderful if it can be solved without changing the grammar.